# Why Isn't my Version of Windows 7 OS Compatible With the Same Version of the Installation CD?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, repair-install

A few days ago, my computer was spontaneously unplugged (instant power out). Since then it won't boot. It says something to the nature of "no bootable media found insert proper boot device." Just to get this out there, there are no USB drives plugged in or anything like that. I even selected the proper hard drive in the boot menu to be sure, and it still says the same thing.

"Great...," I thought, now I have to repair the operating system, but noticed that I could run start up repair, so I tried that first. It gets through it, but doesn't fix the issue and the same problems persist. Next (since I didn't have my Windows key at the time) I pulled the hard drive, plugged it into my wife's laptop, and after a quick use of "ProduKey" to get my OS key, ran a `Chkdsk /f /r` on  it.

After going through all the motions it found, what it stated, to be no problems with the volume. None at all. "Okay, okay, I finally gave up," I'll "repair over the top." When getting the product key with "ProduKey" I was able to verify that my OS version was, in fact, *"Windows 7 Home Premium SP1,"* (and I know it was 64-bit, as well) so, I inserted the appropriate disc (also says *"Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit.* I continued to boot the live CD but as soon as it comes up (maybe after the first screen, I can't remember) it proceeds to tell me that the version on the CD is not compatible with the version that is installed.

*Wait... What?*

I'd never been hit with this before (having the exact same versions and all). Clearly I'm missing something here.

Can something be corrupted enough to cause this *phantom* incompatibility or are there more accurate versions? What next step should I take?

***Things To Note:***

- I haven't yet tried to clear malware as I would have to take it back out and run Malwarebytes, HitmanPro, etc. externally.
- The brand of hard drive I have is *Western Digital* for which I have a bootable CD that can test it, but now, even though it never has before in the years I've owned it, has decided to spontaneously complain about some licensing issue, so no go there either.
- The OS CD that I am trying to repair from, while appears to be the same version, did not actually come with my computer (I actually didn't get a CD (drivers, OS, or any other) with my tower. The OS CD does, however, have the original Microsoft label and info (e.g., it is not just some burned copy that got mislabeled).

As always, any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify the key you extracted is the same key that's printed on the label?

Comment: @Ramhound No, there was no label on the tower (or anyone else) hence my need to get it with ProduKey to begin with. Also, the installation (for repair) doesn't get as far as asking for the product key. The installation CD is NOT the original one, yet boasts to being the same version as the currently installed (however faulty) operating system.

Comment: is the OS DVD actually 7SP1 or just 7? if it's only 7, you can get a legit version of 7SP1 & try from that - Google for refs; there are several on this site - try 'windows 7 legally'

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes the CD ways `Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit` which is exactly the same as the operating system installed (also verified by ProduKey).

Comment: might be worth trying the download - if 6GB of download wouldn't make your ISP wince - for 'just in case'

Comment: @VoidKing - was the tower ORIGINALLY SP1 or was it plain Win 7, then upgraded to SP1? I'm thinking that if it was originally plain Win 7, the DVD might notice the difference and refuse on that basis.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Not sure on that one. Can resetting the BIOS help? I mean may common sense in this field tells me no, but I'm grasping at straws...

Comment: I'm actually worried to do a wipe and reload, because I'm afraid of, somehow, the key not working (since it doesn't see the versions compatible). I'm truly at a loss...

Comment: "it comes up (maybe after the first screen, I can't remember) it proceeds to tell me that the version on the CD is not compatible with the version that is installed" -- Exactly when does this message pop up, and exactly what does it say?

Comment: If your tower does not have a sticker how did you originally enter the key?  Where is the original documentation for the key itself.  ProduKey is known to give invalid keys in my experience at least.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, crap... Well, so far, that's not the problem, since I haven't had a chance to even enter the key (it doesn't get that far) but it could be a problem if I have to wipe and reload (or repair over the top, for that matter).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I didn't realize that it would matter. I'm not at my computer, atm, but I will let you know verbatim, what it says and when, exactly it occurs (I think it occurs just after the first screen where you choose the 'Language,' 'Time,' and 'Keyboard or Input Method' screen).

Comment: Did the Windows 7 installation come with the computer, or did you install it before using this SAME disc? My first thought after reading your question would be you are using an OEM installation + OEM Key, but a retail installation disc.

Comment: @RobinHood I had the same suspicion recently after being told this by my boss. He has lent me an OEM disc. I don't know how I've come as far as I have in computer repair/programming without knowing this, but hey, I'm still just a couple years post graduation.

Comment: @RobinHood I didn't mean to end my last comment so soon. Anyway, was just going to say that I'll try this tonight and let you know. Feel free to make it an answer and I'll remember to accept if it's the answer and upvote either way. Thanks Robin!

Comment: @Ramhound I just realized that I didn't respond to your question. Sorry about that. I never did install the OS. It came installed and I never wiped or reloaded it.

Comment: @VoidKing OEM media is subdivided; a license key that comes with a Dell OEM installation, may not work on an OEM HP installation, or with a generic Microsoft OEM installation. It depends on the license terms for that key.

Comment: @voidKing If it's a major OEM they are required to provide you the sticker with the key.

Comment: @Ramhound I know they are supposed to, but this is special circumstances. I could explain it, but just suffice it to say that the provider of this computer owns a business, but is also a friend. He had this computer built for him and was never provided this stuff himself. I bought it at a lower price because he was in need of the money as I was in need of a good powerful computer. Anyway, I can't seem to find a good (64-bit) OEM so I think a wipe and reload (with one of the Windows 7 Pro keys I have) is unfortunately in order...

Comment: Sounds like he was never provided it because he was never given a legit key... At the very lost he would have a disk kit with the kit if it was legit

Comment: @Ramhound Nah, it was honestly probably just laziness. Never putting the disc in the tower, no sticker on the tower, etc. As I said, it was given to him, but I know the lady that gave it to him, too, though I'm not in contact with her anymore. It was probably just a sloppily done job.